# Google Analitics Reporting API V4 batchGet method needs viewId, but how can one find it?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

In Google Analytics Reporting API V4, here:
[BatchGet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet?authuser=2)
it is written the we need a viewId.

However in other places, including in the Stack overflow issue it says that In Google Analytics 4 (GA4) we not need a viewId any more, as there we use events.

So, how can we actually use the Google Analytics Reporting API V4, the single method present in docs:  [BatchGet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet?authuser=2)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The [Google analytics reporting api v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) uses a view id because it is intended for use with Universal analytics accounts.

A Google Analytics GA4 account is not a universal analytics account and therefore has not view id.

Your issue is that you are looking at the wrong api.  To extract data from a Google Analytics GA4 account you should be using the [Google analytics data API V1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) which is currently in beta.  If you do chose to use that now please remember that it is subject to change and it does change often.